# Unable to get correct frequency value on iphone

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing, core-audio, frequency

I'm trying to analyze frequency detection algorithms on iOS platform. So I found several implementations using FFT and CoreAudio ([example 1](http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/) and [example 2](http://code.google.com/p/ctuner/)). But in both cases there is some imprecision in frequency exists:

- (1) For A4 (440Hz) shows 441.430664 Hz.
- (1) For C6 (1046.5 Hz) shows 1518.09082 Hz.
- (2) For A4 (440Hz) shows 440.72 Hz.
- (2) For C6 (1046.5 Hz) shows 1042.396606 Hz.

Why this happens and how to avoid this problem and detect frequency in more accurate way?

Comment: What's your input's signal-to-noise ratio?  And what is your frequency accuracy target?  The 440 results are already precise to within 1%.

Answer (score 4):

Resolution in the frequency domain is inversely related to number of FFT bins. You need to either:

- increase the size of your FFT to get finer resolution
- use magnitude of adjacent bins to tweak the frequency estimate
- use an alternative method for frequency estimation rather than FFT e.g. parametric model

Comment: I tried to use SampleRate = 22050 and FTT size 4098... But this didn't help.

Comment: For Fs = 22 kHz and FFT size, N = 4096, your resolution will be around 5 Hz. If you need finer resolution than this then N will need to be increased.