# How to get iOS Accelerate FFT results in frequency magnitudes?

Tags: ios, iphone, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I use this code (based on Apple's audioRouch sample):

```
void FFTHelper::ComputeFFT(Float32* inAudioData, Float32* outFFTData)
{
    if (inAudioData == NULL || outFFTData == NULL) return;

    // Generate a split complex vector from the real data
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)inAudioData, 2, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mFFTLength);

    // Take the fft and scale appropriately
    vDSP_fft_zrip(mSpectrumAnalysis, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mLog2N, kFFTDirection_Forward);
    vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, mFFTLength);
    vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, mFFTLength);

    // Zero out the nyquist value
    mDspSplitComplex.imagp[0] = 0.0;

    // Complex vector magnitudes squared; single precision.
    // Calculates the squared magnitudes of complex vector A.
    vDSP_zvmags(&mDspSplitComplex, 1, outFFTData, 1, mFFTLength);

}
```

**To compute FFT on the simplest possible - 1Hz sinus wave** (shifted up by 1 unit):

```
    Float32 waveFreq            = 1.0;
    int     samplesCount        = 1024;
    Float32 samplesPerSecond    = 1000;        //sample rate
    Float32 dt = 1 / samplesPerSecond;
    Float32 sd = M_PI * 2.0 * waveFreq;

    FFTHelper *mFFTHelper = new FFTHelper(samplesCount);

    Float32 NyquistMaxFreq  = samplesPerSecond/2.0;
    Float32 fftDataSize     = samplesCount/2.0;

    Float32 *sinusoidOriginal = (Float32 *)malloc(sizeof(Float32) * samplesCount);
    Float32 *outFFTData = (Float32 *)malloc(sizeof(Float32) * fftDataSize);

    // 2. Generate sin samples:
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesCount; i++) {

        Float32 x = dt * i;
        sinusoidOriginal[i] = sin(sd * x) + 1;
        [originalPlot addVector2D:GLVector2DMake(x, sinusoidOriginal[i])];
    }

    mFFTHelper->ComputeFFT(sinusoidOriginal, outFFTData);

    for (int i = 0; i < fftDataSize; i++) {

            Float32 hz = ((Float32)i / (Float32)fftDataSize) * NyquistMaxFreq;
            GLfloat mag = outFFTData[i];
            [fftPlot addVector2D:GLVector2DMake(hz, 0)];
            [fftPlot addVector2D:GLVector2DMake(hz, mag)];

    }
```

**The result I get is:**

[image]

Black lines are plotter results from FTT, positioned horizontally at their frequencies.
DC value (1st black line from the left) looks OK, correctly represents y = sin(x) + 1 vertical offset.

But why 2nd black line, which represents the only frequency present in sinus equation, **does not have magnitude = 1 and does not exactly stay at 1Hz?**

Can anyone point me to vDSP function to convert FFT results to magnitude units from input signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You seem to be using the code from my answer from this place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966776/468812 
And it's great, but:

You can not avoid these extra frequencies in your signal.

The signal you generate (sin wave) is an infinite signal.
*And if you "crop it" and "only use a piece of the signal" it introduces "clipping noise" at both ends.*

But you can minimize the noise by taking larger input chunks and [using windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) before the FFT. The Accelerate Framework provides some good and simple windowing functions. (Ex. [Hann Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function), [vDSP_hann_window](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_hann_window) )
Also - use larger input chunks. The larger input the more precise is frequency detection.

See [this article](http://www.edn.com/design/systems-design/4376109/The-practicing-instrumentation-engineers-guide-to-the-DFT---Part-2--Spectral-leakage-and-windowing), google: Spectral Leakage, window function.