# How can I get my iPhone to listen for sound frequencies above a certain threshold?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio

I'm interested in getting my iOS app to turn on the microphone and only listen for frequencies above 17000 hz.  If it hears something in that range, I'd like the app to call a method.

I was able to find a repository that detects frequency: https://github.com/krafter/DetectingAudioFrequency

And here is a post breaking down FFT:
[Get Hz frequency from audio stream on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686625/get-hz-frequency-from-audio-stream-on-iphone/19966776#19966776)

Using these examples, I've been able to get the phone to react to the strongest frequency it hears, but  I'm more interested in just reacting to the above 17000 hz frequencies.

Comment: Show some code and perhaps you'll get some assistance. If you've split the incoming sound into frequency buckets then i don't see what your problem is. Hence, show code and explain where you're having difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that I wrote that code helps me answering this question but the answer probably only applies to this code.

You can easily limit the frequencies you listen to just by trimming that output array to a piece that contains only the range you need.

**In details:** To be simple - array[0..255] contains your audio in frequency domain. For example you sample rate was 44100 when you did FFT.
Then maximum frequency you can encode is 22050. (Nyquist theorem).

That is array[0] contains value for 22050/256=86.13 Hz. Array[1] contains value for 86.13*2 = 172.26 Hz, array[2] contains value for 86.13*3 = 258.39 Hz. And so on. Your full range is distributed across those 256 values. (and yes, precision suffers)

So if you only need to listen to some range, let's say above 17000Hz, you just take a piece of that array and ignore the rest. In this case you take 17000/86.13=197 to 255 subarray and you have it. Only 17000-22050 range.

In my repo you modify **strongestFrequencyHZ** function like that:

```
static Float32 strongestFrequencyHZ(Float32 *buffer, FFTHelperRef *fftHelper, UInt32 frameSize, Float32 *freqValue) {
Float32 *fftData = computeFFT(fftHelper, buffer, frameSize);
fftData[0] = 0.0;
unsigned long length = frameSize/2.0;
Float32 max = 0;
unsigned long maxIndex = 0;

Float32 freqLimit = 17000; //HZ

Float32 freqsPerIndex = NyquistMaxFreq/length;
unsigned long lowestLimitIndex = (unsigned long) freqLimit/freqsPerIndex;

unsigned long newLen = length-lowestLimitIndex;
Float32 *newData = fftData+lowestLimitIndex; //address arithmetic
max = vectorMaxValueACC32_index(newData, newLen, 1, &maxIndex);
if (freqValue!=NULL) { *freqValue = max; }
Float32 HZ = frequencyHerzValue(lowestLimitIndex+maxIndex, length, NyquistMaxFreq);
return HZ;
```

}

I did some address arithmetic in there so it looks kind of complicated. You can just take that **fftData** array and do the regular stuff.

**Other things to keep in mind:**

Finding strongest freq. is easy. You just find maximum in that array. That's it. But in you case you need to monitor the range and find when it went from regular weak noise to some strong signal. In other words when stuff peaks, and this is not so trivial, but possible. You can probably just set some limit above which the signal becomes detected, although this not the best option.

I would rather be optimistic about this cause in real life you can't see much noise at 18000Hz around you. The only thing a can remember of are some old TVs that produce that high pitched sound when they're on.

Comment: I made the change, but now I get:  max HZ = 17225.553 printed to my console and on the simulator.  I'm running this in a quiet room, so shouldn't I be getting no value here?

Comment: Because you only listening to the range 17000-22050 you get values only inside that range. As I said before, the real world sound always contains full spectrum of frequencies regardless of how quiet it is. That value you receive is probably because of the fan spinning inside your computer which make it stable value.

Comment: The new modified code only shows strongest freq. inside the 17000-22050 range and nothing else. And there is aways a strongest one.

Comment: @krafter: The code above appears to find the FFT bin with the largest magnitude. There are also cases where this is not actually the frequency with greatest amplitude present in the signal. Remember that the FFT is a set of overlapping band-pass filters.  If the dominant frequency in the signal sits right between two bins, the signal will be split equally (e.g. at -3dB) in two bins adjacent bins.   Even once you've unpicked these situations, this gives - at best - a range of frequencies covered by the peak bin.  The OP's requirement can be achieved more easily with a high-pass filter.

Comment: Well, isn't current implementation a high-pass filter? It is just done in frequency domain. Since OP doesn't need time domain data this works for him. At the end he needs to transmit just a bit of information not the sound itself. As for range of frequencies - yes, every bin is simply a range. In the given example with 256 bins, one has 86.13Hz range, which is not that good. But what if you have 32768 bins? Then the range is just 1.5Hz. This is simply the matter of precision.

Comment: The good old radio stations, I'm pretty sure they don't broadcast at some exact freq., like 101.70000000 Hz or something, they probably fill some small range like 101.65-101.75 and you as a receiver searching for the station are able fall into that range and don't miss it. If searcher chooses a search step less than the range, (e.g. 0.05) he just can't miss it.

Comment: @krafter I got it working great in the simulator...but when I try to run it on my phone, the red microphone bar only comes up for a moment then disappears.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Alan_s, what is the red microphone bar?

Comment: When you activate the microphone on an iPhone, a red bar appears at the top of your phone letting you know that your microphone is on. Looks like this: http://images.tapatalk-cdn.com/15/06/12/d7d50863bdd1ef9648f4c2e35c23c6c4.jpg  Also, I am not getting the "moAudio init or start errors"

Comment: @Alan_s you probably need to turn on the background mode in your app to play audio.

Comment: @krafter It seems like it's the listening that isn't working.  but i'll look into the background mode too.

Comment: @Alan_s, sorry I meant general audio processing, listening and playing in general. Check background audio on iPhone, also check AVAudioSessionCategory - you probably should choose the proper one. (modifications in Info.plist, and beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler methods also involved here)

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm interested, did you get it to work?